# Assign value to array in dictionary: 'numpy.float64' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

I have several images stored as `np.arrays` in a dictionary.

I want to change the value `stackOfImages[1][i][j] = 0` if it is > `0.01`.

My code:

```
for i in range(1392):
  for j in range(891):
    if diffImage[1][i][j] > 0.01:
      diffImageMod[1][i][j] = 0
```

This returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "Subtract-Frames.py", line 54, in <module>
   diffImageMod[1][i][j] = 0
     TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object does not support item assignment
```

What do I have to set the naughty values bigger than `0.01` to zero? I would like to keep the dict data type for the stack of images `diffImageMod`.
Am using Python 2.7.12

Comment: I'm guessing you have a 2-D array an you are treating it as 3-D; My guess is `diffImage` is 3-D and `diffImageMod` is 2-D.

Comment: Yes. Thank you that was the issue!